# django or yii for building a production web app with db and with custom forms and reports

Tags: django, yii

I am trying to choose between django and yii for scalable, maintainable enterprise grade web-app with a database (preferably mysql) backend. The app is mainly focused with data entry but with custom workflows (beyond your basic autogenerated crud forms ) and custom reports. I have a CS background, familiar with MVC, programming background in c++, C#. 8 years ago built a similar app using php, mysql, perl/cgi and remember it being painful (doing everything from scratch with steep learning curve). Need to learn either python or php syntax again but I pick up languages fairly quickly. Read extensively online about django vs yii. Cannot go the .net mvc route due to need for open source. Dabbled in RoR , loved the language but i am not very comfortable with the magic that happens yet, especially for a production grade app. May be in the future. So back to Django vs yii -

**Decision factors are:**
1) easier learning curve
2)better suited framework for specific tasks that I would need - heavy db manipulations, custom UI flow  (nothing too gfx intensive, just regular form elements but where i need to manipulate data over multiple tables via joins etc)
3)no nasty surprises with db connects (read but not fully understood all the gotchas with django orm and mysql).
 
4) something where I am not fighting the framework/language for basic things
5) scalable and fast run time (i know lot depends on how one architect the solution)

Please advice. Looking for help from someone familiar with having worked in both frameworks. thanks a lot

Comment: I have experience with both django and yii....both are loveable...But yii is more loveable..... But django has more performance...almost more than twice that of Yii+apc...... So django is the winner....

Answer (score 12):

I know this is old but I feel like I can add to this, having used both frameworks.

Yii is a solid, fast framework.  It isn't quite as secure out of the box as Django due to certain things (cross-site request forgery protection, for example) not being enabled or enforced by default.  For me the single biggest advantage was the built-in code generator, because once you figure it out and start using it, it basically spits out a full-featured CRUD application in minutes.

Django is my framework of choice, because Python is Django's single biggest advantage.  Not busting on PHP, I actually really like the language, but Python's clean object-oriented-ness (that a word?), class inheritance, etc. really shines with a framework like Django.  There is no built-in code generator in Django, which was a deliberate choice by the developers.  That is both a strength and a weakness.  Yii's code generator can become a bit of a crutch if you're really trying to learn the framework, but with Django, once you learn how it works, you can go in and change anything, because you built it yourself, and it forces you to learn the framework well.  With Yii, when you have your generated code and have to do a customization, THEN you may quickly begin fighting the framework.

Django's ORM is highly flexible, I'm a SQL guy myself and I think I've used raw SQL in my applications exactly once.  Yii's is pretty good but I give Django a leg up in this regard as well, and Django's is extremely well documented.

Installation of Yii is slightly easier than Django, in my experience.  Django takes a bit more work to get up and running.  Django's [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial01/) is much, much stronger than that of Yii, at least it was when I started.

Comment: "..There is no built-in code generator in Django..", isn't django admin -production ready- a code generator ?

Comment: The admin does get created automatically but it doesn't create it in your development file location the way Yii does.  You can customize the admin in Django but mainly via overriding built-in functionality.  Yii, on the other hand, basically leaves you with a set of code that you can then build on and customize directly, which helped me learn much faster.

Comment: Completely agree to you...Python is its greatest strenth...What a framework!

Answer (score 9):

My suggestion would be Django. Forms in Django are classes, and of all the frameworks I've worked in over the past 16 years, from classic ASP to .NET, Rails and Java, I'd put Django's way of doing forms up against any of them.

South makes it ridiculously simple to do schema and data migrations.

I would recommend using Postgres over MySQL, especially if you're going to be leveraging Django ORM, as it's a bit more fine-tuned for Postgres. If you don't need Django admin and you have to use MySQL, you might take a look at SQLAlchemy and Alembic.

Django's learning curve is very flat. It's incredibly easy to learn and is extremely well documented.

My $0.02.

Comment: thanks so much for the responses. I will check Django out. One other question - i have heard django projects are more difficult to deploy on apache servers than say a php based one. any idea if this is the case?

Comment: Not at all. Almost all of my freelance apps are deployed to WebFaction, directly from Beanstalk with a single click. Setting up a Django environment at WebFaction is two clicks. At my work, we deploy to AWS using Fabric and autoscale from there. It's really quite simple.

Answer (score 5):

Yii is superb. I could learn it and get going within a couple of hours. I struggled to setup Django because of confusing configuration and URL mapping that is needed to get anything working. I have no doubt Django is excellent once you learn it but in my experience Yii was a lot easier to learn.

I really wish someone would port Yii to python.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some comparisons on both frameworks...

http://blog.leehsueh.com/2010/03/django-vs-yii/

http://vschart.com/compare/yii/vs/django-framework

Comment: thank you. I had looked at the general comparisons but didnt know for my specific case.